# Form Collection Returning Two Values, How to read First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, .net-4.0

My form is posting values to the controller, and in Form Collection, some Keys have one values, and while some others have two values, I Intend to read the first values of all the keys in Form Collection, Any Help ??

1. Key: A   Value:[0]:True, [1]: False
2. Key: B   Value:[0]: False
3. Key: C   Value:[0]: False
4. Key: D   Value:[0]:True, [1]: False

I only want Value[0] for each key !!

Comment: I'm curious as to how a Key can have multiple values.  Are you implying that your "Value" is a collection of some type?  Or is it some kind of Tuple<> or something?

Comment: Can you post the views form that you have so we can get a better idea what it is you are trying to submit please?

Comment: Amarnath just answered the question, Thanks all !! :)

Comment: CodeHxr it's because MVC renders a hidden checkbox so we get both values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amarnath's answer is correct but using a split is unnecessary as the GetValues() method already does that for you.

```
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection fc)
{
     foreach (string key in fc.AllKeys)
     {
          string value-to-consider = fc.GetValues(key).FirstOrDefault();

          //further processing.
     }

}
```

Edit: I would have added this as a comment if I had the ability to do so.

Comment: I believe the two answers could be merged. Perhaps a comment would have been more appropriate, so that the author could update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The form collection returns comma separated values for the specified key, you can use split(",") to separate all values and can only consider first value. A sample implementation will be

```
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection fc)
{
     foreach (string key in fc.AllKeys)
     {
          string values = fc[key];
          string[] valueArray = values.split(',');
          string value-to-consider = valueArray[0];

          //further processing.
     }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happens if a value contains a comma? Is it escaped somehow?